# Laravel 4: how to "order by" using Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Simple question - how do I order by 'id' descending in Laravel 4.

The relevant part of my controller looks like this:

```
$posts = $this->post->all()
```

As I understand you use this line:

```
->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
```

But how does that fit in with my above code?

Comment: Couldn't you do something like:     $posts = $this->post->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

Comment: Yep, sorry I was having trouble with the syntax. Thanks - If you post that as an answer I will happily selected it as the correct answer.

Comment: in laravel 5 you can use: ->orderByDesc('id');

Answer (score 524, accepted):

If you are using post as a model (without dependency injection), you can also do:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: This is the way to go when using version 4!

Comment: Still works in 5.1

Comment: also working in 5.3

Comment: Absolutely still working in 5.4

Comment: working fine in 5.5 also

Comment: works in 5.6 too

Comment: i'll save the next guy from having to post in the future, works in 5.7 too

Comment: valid in 2019 and in all versions.

Comment: lol @westcoast, working in 5.8.

Comment: Working in 6.2 too

Comment: Does not work in laravel 7

Comment: It does still work in Laravel 7

Comment: dafuq happen here

Comment: oh my goodness still working in laravel 8 in 2021

Comment: It works in all version including laravel 9

Comment: works in laravel 10 too!

Comment: still working in laravel 10.46.0 :-)

Answer (score 76):

If you are using the Eloquent ORM you should consider using scopes. This would keep your logic in the model where it belongs.

So, in the model you would have:

```
public function scopeIdDescending($query)
{
        return $query->orderBy('id','DESC');
}
```

And outside the model you would have:

```
$posts = Post::idDescending()->get();
```

More info: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: where is the query being passed to `idDescending()`  in the last line `$posts = Post::idDescending()->get();`

Comment: Laravel parses that automatically.

Comment: I would go with this answer. Here's how I do it normally on my everyday work: Within the mode: ```public function scopeLatest($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('created_at')->get();
    }```

And within the controller: ```return view('project.view')->with(['projects' => Project::latest()]);```

Comment: I like this answer the best vs handling in-line, esp if you are handling multiple order conditions. Thanks!

`_.orderBy(this.users, ['name', 'last_login'], ['asc', 'desc'])`

Answer (score 40):

This is how I would go about it.

```
$posts = $this->post->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```