# Laravel 5 Model orderBy?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I see you can call my `MyModel::all()` and then call "where" "groupBy" .. etc
I cant seem to find `orderBy` as this [Q & A suggest..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18289241)
Has this been removed in Laravel 5?

I've tried looking through the docs for a reference in [Collection](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) and [Model](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html) but I'm assuming these are actually just modifiers for the collection returned and not actually modifying the query statement..

The only way I know of using order by is

```
\DB::table($table)->where($column)->orderBy($column);
```

Is that the only way to order your database select when executing a query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually just use it like `where` and `groupBy`:

```
$result = MyModel::orderBy('name', 'desc')->get();
```

Note that by calling `MyModel::all()` you're already executing the query.

---

In general you can pretty much use every method from the query builder documented [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries) with Eloquent models. The reason for this is that the model proxies method calls (that it doesn't know) to a query builder instance:

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    // irrelevant code omitted

    $query = $this->newQuery();

    return call_user_func_array(array($query, $method), $parameters);
}
```

`$this->newQuery()` creates an instance of the query builder which then is used to actually run the query. Then when the result is retrieved the model/collection is *hydrated* with the values from the database.

---

**More info**

[Eloquent - Laravel 5 Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent)

[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder - API docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html)

And also the regular query builder (since quite a few calls get passed from the eloquent builder)
[Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder - API docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html)

Comment: Interesting... I was expecting it to not work since there was no code hinting  suggesting it in my IDE (Netbeans with laravel ide helper). Do these calls have any documentation? I must be blind

Comment: @DesignerGuy Thanks. Not to forget the actual query builder because many calls just get passed from the eloquent builder...

Comment: @StrikeForceZero For better IDE coverage when using Laravel, use this: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the following solution:

```
$result = ModelName::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using sort keys

```
Model::all()->sortKeys()
```

(or)

```
Model::all()->sortKeysDesc()
```