# Laravel - sorting table by column titles, results not being sorted

Tags: php, sorting, laravel-5

I am using [Kyslik/column-sortable](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable) in my Laravel 5.4 CRUD project for added sortable column headers.

the model:

```
use Sortable;
// 
public $sortable = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

the view:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th> @sortablelink('id','#') </th>
             <th> @sortablelink('name') </th>
             ...
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

and the controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $keyword = $request->get('search');
    //dd($request);
    if (!empty($keyword)) {
        $customers = Customer::where('name', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->sortable()
            ->paginate(config('settings.perPage'));
    } else {
        $customers = Customer::paginate(config('settings.perPage'));
    }

    return view('admin.customers.index', compact('customers'));
}
```

The view and the column header links show up and work exactly as expected, but the results aren't sorted at all... What am I missing?

Comment: `->sortable()->orderBy('name','ASC')`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553181/laravel-4-how-to-order-by-using-eloquent-orm

Comment: @SimonMüller from looking at the documentation, my understanding was that you needed to do that only if you wanted a default sort field+dir. Otherwise, it should pick it up directly from the request sent to the controller: https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable/blob/L5.4/src/ColumnSortable/Sortable.php#L24-L39

Answer (score 0):

In your view page
@sortablelink should have two arguments

1. Column name in Database
2. Column heading in table

So,
@sortablelink('name','Name')
This might help you.