# Using PHP array or SQL, how can I sequence items of an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-5.3

This array was sorted ascending by time.

```
A    | B    | C
-----+------+--------------------
23/3 | 2001 | 2017-10-25 09:35:52
23/3 | 2002 | 2017-10-25 09:45:00
25/2 | 5001 | 2017-10-25 10:30:00
23/3 | 2003 | 2017-10-25 11:30:00
25/2 | 5002 | 2017-10-25 12:30:00
```

Now I want to sequence items of A, like in the table below. Using PHP, how can I do this?

```
A    | B    | C
-----+------+--------------------
23/3 | 2001 | 2017-10-25 09:35:52
23/3 | 2002 | 2017-10-25 09:45:00
23/3 | 2003 | 2017-10-25 11:30:00
25/2 | 5001 | 2017-10-25 10:30:00
25/2 | 5002 | 2017-10-25 12:30:00
```

Comment: change query sql, to made DESC?

Comment: By sequence, don't you mean [sort](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sort.php) ?

Comment: What is the sorting logic you are using here?  Both columns `A` and `B` are sorted in ascending order, but maybe you even have something else in mind.

Comment: The sample data provided makes this question ambiguous and unclear.  Please improve your question.  Better still, take the time to research how to use mysql's `ORDER BY` clause via the manual or StackOverflow.  All users are expected to do their research before posting a question and the question should include a coding attempt.  This is surely a duplicate question.

Comment: only upper tabe is ascending order but last table is not ascending order look  at C.

Comment: I don't use Laravel, but perhaps someone else will know if this is a fitting duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553181/laravel-4-how-to-order-by-using-eloquent-orm

Comment: @mickmackusa i tried Order by, Group by but here is not the case look c last table after getting ascending data from upper table i have to sort data like 23/3 three data have to same serial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several column for sorting in your query.
Here is the code :

```
Select * from table order by table.a, table.c
```

Answer (score 0):

First order the A column in ascending order and then order the C column in ascending order.

SQL Query will be like @Derta's answer.