# Laravel, get the minimum price within subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

Having the below working code:

```
$greatDeals = Deal::whereHas('hotel', function ($query) {
                        $query->whereHas('room', function ($query) {
                            $query->Where('astatus', 1)->Where('status', 0);
                        })->Where('astatus', 1)->Where('status', 0);
                    })->with(['hotel' => function ($query) {
                        $query->with('room')->get(); //need to get minimum price from room table
                    }])
                    ->where('date', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
                    ->where('status', 1)
                    ->orderBy('discount', 'desc')
                    ->limit(9)
                    ->get();
```

In the above query i `need to get minimum price from room table` is it possible with existing query?

**Update:** my current result:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":5,
      "hotel_id":1,
      "deal_code":"units",
      "date":"2018-03-30 00:00:00",
      "discount":80,
      "status":1,
      "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:55:32",
      "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:55:32",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "client_id":2,
      "hotel":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Testing Grounds",
         "address":"1-23 City Rd, Southbank VIC 3006, Australia",
         "phone":"9842814927",
         "country":"4",
         "country_name":"American Samoa",
         "state":"166",
         "state_name":"Swains Island",
         "city":"48331",
         "city_name":"Swains Island",
         "area":"test",
         "pincode":"3006",
         "nearest_airport":"test",
         "nearest_railway":"teste",
         "star":"5",
         "check_in":"05:15 AM",
         "check_out":"10:30 AM",
         "lat":"-39",
         "lng":"144.967621",
         "description":"tsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaa",
         "astatus":"1",
         "status":"0",
         "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:28:28",
         "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:31:22",
         "client_id":2,
         "hotel_age":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_privilege":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "departure":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "checkout_fee":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "book_policy":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsad",
         "hotel_secured":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_pets":"Allowed",
         "hotel_other":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "room":[  
            {  
               "id":2,
               "roomtype_id":1,
               "room_count":null,
               "max_adult":2,
               "max_children":2,
               "capacity":4,
               "room_number":null,
               "floor":null,
               "number":null,
               "name":null,
               "city_name":"Swains Island",
               "city":48331,
               "price":"500.00",
               "extra_bed_price":null,
               "astatus":"1",
               "status":"0",
               "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:51:17",
               "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:52:20",
               "deleted_at":null,
               "client_id":2,
               "hotel_id":1
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":4,
      "hotel_id":1,
      "deal_code":"unit",
      "date":"2018-03-28 00:00:00",
      "discount":70,
      "status":1,
      "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:55:09",
      "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:55:09",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "client_id":2,
      "hotel":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Testing Grounds",
         "address":"1-23 City Rd, Southbank VIC 3006, Australia",
         "phone":"9842814927",
         "country":"4",
         "country_name":"American Samoa",
         "state":"166",
         "state_name":"Swains Island",
         "city":"48331",
         "city_name":"Swains Island",
         "area":"test",
         "pincode":"3006",
         "nearest_airport":"test",
         "nearest_railway":"teste",
         "star":"5",
         "check_in":"05:15 AM",
         "check_out":"10:30 AM",
         "lat":"-39",
         "lng":"144.967621",
         "description":"tsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaa",
         "astatus":"1",
         "status":"0",
         "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:28:28",
         "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:31:22",
         "client_id":2,
         "hotel_age":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_privilege":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "departure":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "checkout_fee":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "book_policy":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsad",
         "hotel_secured":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_pets":"Allowed",
         "hotel_other":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "room":[  
            {  
               "id":2,
               "roomtype_id":1,
               "room_count":null,
               "max_adult":2,
               "max_children":2,
               "capacity":4,
               "room_number":null,
               "floor":null,
               "number":null,
               "name":null,
               "city_name":"Swains Island",
               "city":48331,
               "price":"500.00",
               "extra_bed_price":null,
               "astatus":"1",
               "status":"0",
               "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:51:17",
               "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:52:20",
               "deleted_at":null,
               "client_id":2,
               "hotel_id":1
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":1,
      "hotel_id":1,
      "deal_code":"test",
      "date":"2018-03-23 00:00:00",
      "discount":50,
      "status":1,
      "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:54:26",
      "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:54:26",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "client_id":2,
      "hotel":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Testing Grounds",
         "address":"1-23 City Rd, Southbank VIC 3006, Australia",
         "phone":"9842814927",
         "country":"4",
         "country_name":"American Samoa",
         "state":"166",
         "state_name":"Swains Island",
         "city":"48331",
         "city_name":"Swains Island",
         "area":"test",
         "pincode":"3006",
         "nearest_airport":"test",
         "nearest_railway":"teste",
         "star":"5",
         "check_in":"05:15 AM",
         "check_out":"10:30 AM",
         "lat":"-39",
         "lng":"144.967621",
         "description":"tsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaa",
         "astatus":"1",
         "status":"0",
         "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:28:28",
         "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:31:22",
         "client_id":2,
         "hotel_age":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_privilege":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "departure":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "checkout_fee":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "book_policy":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsad",
         "hotel_secured":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_pets":"Allowed",
         "hotel_other":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "room":[  
            {  
               "id":2,
               "roomtype_id":1,
               "room_count":null,
               "max_adult":2,
               "max_children":2,
               "capacity":4,
               "room_number":null,
               "floor":null,
               "number":null,
               "name":null,
               "city_name":"Swains Island",
               "city":48331,
               "price":"500.00",
               "extra_bed_price":null,
               "astatus":"1",
               "status":"0",
               "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:51:17",
               "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:52:20",
               "deleted_at":null,
               "client_id":2,
               "hotel_id":1
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "hotel_id":1,
      "deal_code":"test",
      "date":"2018-03-24 00:00:00",
      "discount":50,
      "status":1,
      "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:54:41",
      "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:54:41",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "client_id":2,
      "hotel":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Testing Grounds",
         "address":"1-23 City Rd, Southbank VIC 3006, Australia",
         "phone":"9842814927",
         "country":"4",
         "country_name":"American Samoa",
         "state":"166",
         "state_name":"Swains Island",
         "city":"48331",
         "city_name":"Swains Island",
         "area":"test",
         "pincode":"3006",
         "nearest_airport":"test",
         "nearest_railway":"teste",
         "star":"5",
         "check_in":"05:15 AM",
         "check_out":"10:30 AM",
         "lat":"-39",
         "lng":"144.967621",
         "description":"tsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaa",
         "astatus":"1",
         "status":"0",
         "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:28:28",
         "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:31:22",
         "client_id":2,
         "hotel_age":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_privilege":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "departure":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "checkout_fee":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "book_policy":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsad",
         "hotel_secured":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_pets":"Allowed",
         "hotel_other":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "room":[  
            {  
               "id":2,
               "roomtype_id":1,
               "room_count":null,
               "max_adult":2,
               "max_children":2,
               "capacity":4,
               "room_number":null,
               "floor":null,
               "number":null,
               "name":null,
               "city_name":"Swains Island",
               "city":48331,
               "price":"500.00",
               "extra_bed_price":null,
               "astatus":"1",
               "status":"0",
               "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:51:17",
               "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:52:20",
               "deleted_at":null,
               "client_id":2,
               "hotel_id":1
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {  
      "id":12,
      "hotel_id":1,
      "deal_code":"tests",
      "date":"2018-03-22 00:00:00",
      "discount":35,
      "status":1,
      "created_at":"2018-03-21 08:59:22",
      "updated_at":"2018-03-21 08:59:22",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "client_id":2,
      "hotel":{  
         "id":1,
         "name":"Testing Grounds",
         "address":"1-23 City Rd, Southbank VIC 3006, Australia",
         "phone":"9842814927",
         "country":"4",
         "country_name":"American Samoa",
         "state":"166",
         "state_name":"Swains Island",
         "city":"48331",
         "city_name":"Swains Island",
         "area":"test",
         "pincode":"3006",
         "nearest_airport":"test",
         "nearest_railway":"teste",
         "star":"5",
         "check_in":"05:15 AM",
         "check_out":"10:30 AM",
         "lat":"-39",
         "lng":"144.967621",
         "description":"tsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaatsaa",
         "astatus":"1",
         "status":"0",
         "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:28:28",
         "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:31:22",
         "client_id":2,
         "hotel_age":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_privilege":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "departure":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "checkout_fee":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "book_policy":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsad",
         "hotel_secured":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "hotel_pets":"Allowed",
         "hotel_other":"asfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsaasfsadfsa",
         "room":[  
            {  
               "id":2,
               "roomtype_id":1,
               "room_count":null,
               "max_adult":2,
               "max_children":2,
               "capacity":4,
               "room_number":null,
               "floor":null,
               "number":null,
               "name":null,
               "city_name":"Swains Island",
               "city":48331,
               "price":"500.00",
               "extra_bed_price":null,
               "astatus":"1",
               "status":"0",
               "created_at":"2018-03-16 07:51:17",
               "updated_at":"2018-03-16 07:52:20",
               "deleted_at":null,
               "client_id":2,
               "hotel_id":1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

ignore this text  ignore this text  ignore this text  ignore this text  ignore this text  ignore this text  ignore this text  ignore this text  ignore this ignore this text  ignore this text

Comment: What is the format of the collection returned? And I guess you want the min price using a collection method (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-min) ... otherwise I think you need another query.

Comment: No , That not Possible . reason behind it is generate error in you try to get data in subquery , becuase  the structure of query is not proper if you try to get data in subquery

Comment: what variable name you have used to define price in your table?

Comment: @ChiragPatel `price`

Comment: @arunkumar are you getting a result with this query? like deals?

Comment: @ChiragPatel, see the updated text, my current result is updated

Comment: try use orderBy('price','ASC')->get() [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553181/laravel-4-how-to-order-by-using-eloquent-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553181/laravel-4-how-to-order-by-using-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see it working is pretty resource consuming

```
$minPrice = 10000000;
$roomId = 0;
$dealId = 0;

$result->each(function($item, $key) use (&$minPrice, &$roomid, &$dealId){
     if($value->hotel->room->price < $minPrice){
          $minPrice = $value->room->price;
          $roomId = $value->room->id;
          $dealId = $value->id;
     }
});
```

I would recommend changing the query. Let me know if you need help with that.

Also can a hotel have multiple rooms? If yes there's another query there

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel aggregate method **min** in your query,

```
$query->with('room')->min('price');
```

I am not sure it will work or not but you can try this.
Just paste this code to try,

```
$greatDeals = Deal::whereHas('hotel', function ($query) {
                        $query->whereHas('room', function ($query) {
                            $query->Where('astatus', 1)->Where('status', 0);
                        })->Where('astatus', 1)->Where('status', 0);
                    })->with(['hotel' => function ($query) {
                        $query->with('room')->min('price'); //need to get minimum price from room table
                    }])
                    ->where('date', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
                    ->where('status', 1)
                    ->orderBy('discount', 'desc')
                    ->limit(9)
                    ->get();
```

If there will be error. Tell me I will find another query.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'price' in 'field list' (SQL: select min(`price`) as aggregate from `hotels` where `hotels`.`id` in (1, 6))`

Comment: ->with('hotels.rooms')

Comment: what is the relation between Deal and Hotel? it's 'hotel' or 'hotels'?