# How to give order query when using scorp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get image data. giving order by id desc.
I add orderBy sentece after get() it didn't work.
Could you teach me how to add order query when using :: scope?

```
public function index()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::get()->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        return view('image-gallery',compact('images'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to orderBy on a Collection (after your `get()`) - you should run it on the query (before your `get()`)

```
public function index()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('image-gallery',compact('images'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query.

```
public function index()
    {
        $images = ImageGallery::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        return view('image-gallery',compact('images'));
    }
```

Refer this

[orderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553181/laravel-4-how-to-order-by-using-eloquent-orm)