# I need to display latest entry in first

Tags: php, laravel

My Controller Query to show the datas as Follows (in laravel)

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = $this->jobRepository->prepareJobData();
    $data['input'] = $request->all();

    return view('web.jobs.index')->with($data);
}
```

### My PrepareJobdata fuction

```
 public function prepareJobData()
{
    $data['jobTypes'] = JobType::pluck('name', 'id');
    $data['jobCategories'] = JobCategory::pluck('name', 'id');
    $data['jobSkills'] = Skill::pluck('name', 'id');
    $data['genders'] = Job::NO_PREFERENCE;
    $data['careerLevels'] = CareerLevel::pluck('level_name', 'id');
    $data['functionalAreas'] = FunctionalArea::pluck('name', 'id');

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: php laravel framework  Robert Anthony S. Tribiana

Comment: Please see my answer

Comment: in which function i can add this  Robert Anthony S. Tribiana

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 4: how to "order by" using Eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553181/laravel-4-how-to-order-by-using-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these

```
->orderBy('created_At', 'desc')->first();
```

or

```
->latest('created_At')->first();
```

Please use ->get() for the last if you don't want to return the last row only instead, multiple rows

Comment: public function prepareJobData()
    {
        $data['jobTypes'] = JobType::pluck('name', 'id');
        $data['jobCategories'] = JobCategory::pluck('name', 'id');
        $data['jobSkills'] = Skill::pluck('name', 'id');
        $data['genders'] = Job::NO_PREFERENCE;
        $data['careerLevels'] = CareerLevel::pluck('level_name', 'id');
        $data['functionalAreas'] = FunctionalArea::pluck('name', 'id');

        return $data;
    }   this is my function how i can write  Robert Anthony S. Tribiana

Comment: I updated my answer. check the last line. Do you need the last row only or multiple rows?

Comment: its showing error Robert Anthony S. Tribiana

Comment: its showing error Robert Anthony S. Tribiana

Answer (score 0):

In your `prepareJobData()` method you can chain this:

```php
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

// or simply
->latest()->get(); // ordered by created_at
```

**Edit:** So, it seems to be doing some formating which might not be the best approach. But anyway, something like this should do the trick.

```
public function prepareJobData()
{
    $data['jobTypes'] = JobType::latest()->pluck('name', 'id');
    $data['jobCategories'] = JobCategory::latest()->pluck('name', 'id');
    $data['jobSkills'] = Skill::latest()->pluck('name', 'id');
    $data['genders'] = Job::NO_PREFERENCE;
    $data['careerLevels'] = CareerLevel::latest()->pluck('level_name', 'id');
    $data['functionalAreas'] = FunctionalArea::latest()->pluck('name', 'id');

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: how i can write that P. K. Tharindu

Comment: public function prepareJobData()
    {
        $data['jobTypes'] = JobType::pluck('name', 'id');
        $data['jobCategories'] = JobCategory::pluck('name', 'id');
        $data['jobSkills'] = Skill::pluck('name', 'id');
        $data['genders'] = Job::NO_PREFERENCE;
        $data['careerLevels'] = CareerLevel::pluck('level_name', 'id');
        $data['functionalAreas'] = FunctionalArea::pluck('name', 'id');

        return $data;
    }

Comment: Check the updated answer :)